# Quebra de linha dentro de string que está dentro de uma template string

Tags: javascript, string

Eu sei que para quebrar linhas dentro de string, usamos o operador `\n`.
Também sei que dentro de template strings, conseguimos fazer usando apenas a barra invertida, desta forma.

```
var string = `Uma linha \
duas linhas \
três linhas`
```

Até ai, ok.
Mas e se eu tenho uma string dentro de uma template string, e preciso quebrar linha dentro dela? Exemplo:

```
var string2 = `$(this).text(var1 + "\n_________________\n")`
```

No caso preciso passar esta linha de código dentro de uma template string para outra variável que irá inserir o código direto na tag de script da página. Usar \n me dá erro de sintaxe, e usar o estilo de barra invertida dos template strings não pula a linha, apenas cria um espaço enorme no lugar da barra invertida. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Não deu para entender direito. Você quer passar o código em JavaScript como uma string, para depois usar algo como eval? Acredito que existam formas melhores de fazer isso. O erro de sintaxe que você mencionou também não ficou claro, mas imagino que seja porque o `\n` está quebrando linhas. Se for o caso talvez você deva escapar o código com `$(this).text(var1 + "\\n_________________\\n")`

Comment: Não, eu não uso o eval().
A questão é que eu preciso inserir uma tabela dinamica via script num formulário, e colocar o script "fora" da tabela não funciona por que por alguma razão ela não reconhece nenhum script externo. Então eu crio junto o html uma tag script e escrevo os scripts dentro dessa tag. Vou tentar o que você sugeriu e te retorno se funcionou, um seg.

Comment: Usar o `\\n` funcionou, muito obrigado. Se quiser escreva uma resposta q eu dou como aceita.